# Python mysql connector connection not listening to updates from phpMyAdmin or other connections

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have an issue with python mysql-connector where anything done through phpMyAdmin doesn't exists in my inital connection unless I kill it and start it again. For example if I start a python script with a mysql-connector connection that prints everything in a table, then go to phpMyAdmin and update a row attribute, then prompts my python script to print the table, the update I did wouldn't be there. But it works the other way around, any updates the python script does can be seen in phpMyAdmin

Comment: I would look at the connection parameters you have used in your python script

Comment: Does _then prompts my python script to print the table_ mean you rerun the query or just print what already on the page? I know its a silly question but its not clear from your question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Basically just call a function to query then print results (During runtime, as the script continues to run like a "server")